# How to draw a line based on mouse move using Raphael.JS

Tags: raphael, graphael

I am trying to draw a line along with mouse move on a paper. I just know how to draw a line using `path`. But wanted to know if anyone have ideas to make drawing a line along with `mousemove`. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here a link to such example using raphael

[Drawing with Raphael.(Credit:Jonas).](http://irunmywebsite.com/raphael/drawtool2.php) (click view->source to see how its done...)

[And a jsfiddle that I did just in case](http://jsfiddle.net/vedmack/9f4wM/)(`just for back up`)

It uses the [drag](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.drag) and [mousemove](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.mousemove) events of raphael over a rectangle element...