# How can I bind a Raphael element to the mouse cursor?

Tags: javascript, raphael

I want to create an element and then have that element be immediately bound to the cursor. I have tools to move the element, but I don't know how to bind them to the cursor without having to click the element. I thought about simulating the mousedown() event, but I don't know how to do it.

For context, my ultimate goal is to create a line with user defined endpoint. The user clicks a point and 2 small black circles are created. One as a reference point the the first click and the other to be attached to the cursor with a path connect the 2 points. Once the user clicks another point, both small black circles with disappear and only the line will remain.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could bind to mousemove to get the mouse position. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975886/how-to-draw-a-line-based-on-mouse-move-using-raphael-js).

Comment: @JoanCharmant thanks for pointing that out to me. The question you referenced help me to come to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Joan Charmant for pointing me in the right direction. Here's my solution thus far. $('#paper') is my canvas and tempPoint is the circle I created to bind to cursor movement.

```
$("#paper").mousemove(function (event)
                {
                    if(firstLinePointSelected && tempPoint!=null)
                    {
                        if (!event) var event = window.event;
                        var x=0, y=0;
                        if (event.pageX || event.pageY)     
                        {
                            x = event.pageX;
                            y = event.pageY;
                        }
                        else if (event.clientX || event.clientY)    
                        {                           
                            x = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft
                                + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
                            y = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop
                                + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
                        }

                        // subtract paper coords on page
                        tempPoint.attr("cx", x - $('#paper').offset().left);
                        tempPoint.attr("cy", y - $('#paper').offset().top);
                    }
                });
```